# How to show different states of India using choropleth plotly map

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot India map using plotly just wanted plot similar to USA
[enter image description here][1]

```
 fig_choropleth = px.choropleth(dff, locations='state', geojson=india_states, featureidkey='properties.ST_NM',locationmode='geojson-id', color='content_view',scope='asia')
```

it shows entire Asia scope

[i wanted India specific just like USA with differentiated states][2]
fig_choropleth.update_geos(fitbounds="geojson", visible=False)

if i use this in addition of above code the result as follows

[enter image description here][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBWUm.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGtJE.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBEta.png

Answer (score 0):

Your images aren't showing in SO.  The code you want:

```
# restrict to just India
fig_choropleth.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
```

You have noted how to ensure all states are displayed.  This can be done by building a base trace then adding subset of states as a Choropleth

#### full MWE with Indian state geojson and simulated data frame

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# get some geojson for India.  Reduce somplexity of geomtry to make it more efficient
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Subhash9325/GeoJson-Data-of-Indian-States/master/Indian_States"
gdf = gpd.read_file(url)
gdf["geometry"] = gdf.to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs()).simplify(1000).to_crs(gdf.crs)
india_states = gdf.rename(columns={"NAME_1": "ST_NM"}).__geo_interface__

# simulate data frame
dff = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "state": ['Andaman and Nicobar', 'Andhra Pradesh', 'Arunachal Pradesh', 'Assam', 'Bihar', 'Chandigarh', 'Chhattisgarh', 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli', 'Daman and Diu', 'Delhi', 'Goa', 'Gujarat', 'Haryana', 'Himachal Pradesh', 'Jammu and Kashmir', 'Jharkhand', 'Karnataka', 'Kerala', 'Lakshadweep', 'Madhya Pradesh', 'Maharashtra', 'Manipur', 'Meghalaya', 'Mizoram', 'Nagaland', 'Orissa', 'Puducherry', 'Punjab', 'Rajasthan', 'Sikkim', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Tripura', 'Uttar Pradesh', 'Uttaranchal', 'West Bengal'],  # fmt: skip
        "content_view": np.random.randint(1, 5, 35),
    }
)

# data frame only has a subset of states...
dff = dff.sample(20)

# create base map of all India states
fig_choropleth = px.choropleth(
    pd.json_normalize(india_states["features"])["properties.ST_NM"],
    locations="properties.ST_NM",
    geojson=india_states,
    featureidkey="properties.ST_NM",
    color_discrete_sequence=["lightgrey"],
)


# users code to generate choropleth
fig_choropleth.add_traces(
    px.choropleth(
        dff,
        locations="state",
        geojson=india_states,
        featureidkey="properties.ST_NM",
        locationmode="geojson-id",
        color="content_view",
        scope="asia",
    ).data
)

# restrict to just India
fig_choropleth.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig_choropleth
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob ,i had a doubt in locations =state ,where all states are selected in our code so states gets highlighted , if few states not their in the data frame will it be not highlighted  and shown like  case  USA

Comment: updated.... build a base layer then add traces to it